# Java script value passing gives same value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here am using a websocket script. I want to pass the value of 'message' in the button to webapp.js  . But am getting only one same  value in every button click.

Javascript Section

```
</script><script src="webapp.js"></script>
```

Database connection

```
 <?php
//open the database

$db = new PDO('sqlite:server.db');   
$result = $db->query('SELECT Room_Name,Id FROM FavoritesDetails     
WHERE Room_Name="Bed Room" AND Id != "" ');

  ?>
```

Php Code

```
  <form id="message-form" action="#" method="post">
  <section id="mainroom" class="parallax fullscreen" style="background: url('images/roomm.jpg')">
  <div class="container container-fullscreen text-light text-center">
             <div class="text-middle">
                          <?php 

                              foreach($result as $row)
                        { ?> 

<button class="button button1" type="submit" id="message" value="<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>" onclick="myFunction(this)"><?php echo $row['Id']; ?></button>
   <?php
    }
   ?>   
    </div>
   </div>
   </form>
```

webapp.js

```
window.onload = function() {

// Get references to elements on the page.



var form = document.getElementById('message-form');
var messageField = document.getElementById('message');


var messagesList = document.getElementById('messages');
var socketStatus = document.getElementById('status');
var closeBtn = document.getElementById('close');


 // Create a new WebSocket.
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:9300');


// Handle any errors that occur.
socket.onerror = function(error) {
console.log('WebSocket Error: ' + error);
 };


 // Show a connected message when the WebSocket is opened.
socket.onopen = function(event) {
socketStatus.innerHTML = 'Connected to: ' + event.currentTarget.URL;
 socketStatus.className = 'open';
  };


 // Handle messages sent by the server.
 socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  var message = event.data;
  messagesList.innerHTML += '<li class="received"><span>Received: 
 </span>' +
                           message + '</li>';
 };


// Show a disconnected message when the WebSocket is closed.
 socket.onclose = function(event) {
socketStatus.innerHTML = 'Disconnected from WebSocket.';
socketStatus.className = 'closed';
};


// Send a message when the form is submitted.

form.onsubmit = function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

// Retrieve the message from the textarea.
var message = messageField.value;

// Send the message through the WebSocket.
socket.send(message);

// Add the message to the messages list.
messagesList.innerHTML += '<li class="sent"><span>Sent:</span>' +  
message +
                          '</li>';

// Clear out the message field.
messageField.value = '';

return false;
};


// Close the WebSocket connection when the close button is clicked.
closeBtn.onclick = function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

// Close the WebSocket.
socket.close();

return false;
};

};
```

Comment: <button class="button button1" type="submit" class="message" value="<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>" onclick="myFunction(this)"><?php echo $row['Id']; ?></button>
In one page id will be unique so please use class

Comment: as @sumandas wrote, if you have multiple elements with the same `id` so query take the first one always. use `data-id` instead.

Comment: Then How? I dont Know more about Javascript